# Set up a server and get feed from it in android

Tags: android, web-services

This may not be the type of question I am supposed to ask here but I don't have anywhere else to go. I want to make an android application which gets feed from a web-server and displays in the application. It will be kind of a newspaper app. I have done my share of work: I know android application developemnt: have made some apps. Also, I have an idea of UI: a listview with the feeds and then on selecting an element I will open another activity with the complete feed. What I wanted to know is:

1. How to set-up a server for this?
2. How to request?
3. Can I set-up a free server?

I dont want to use GCM as I don't think it allows sending pictures. Plus it allows small data to be sent. Also, I have no knowledge about the 3rd party server I may need to create for this.

I would want to post both text and photos (combined makes a post, total of around 10 posts) from the server. Please dont close as not a question. Any link, tutorial will be highly appreciated. For server side coding, I know php, .net. I have never coded in java for a server, but I can learn it.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow following steps to get your project done.

1. Set up any php or Java or .Net Server (If you are aware of any of these web technologies)
2. After you set up server you need to make web service which will work as mediator to transfer data between your server and mobile.
3. Webservice response will be either in JSON or XML
4. Generate response according to your need and parse them on android side.
5. Display in listview :) :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use JBOSS for your server, and do a Java Server with Webservices.

In your webservices you'll have a service that get all the feeds, and maybe another that request the complete feed...

Your "language" between the Android app and the Server, you can use XML with SOAP (ksoap2 for Android), or you can try JSON (I never used, but I will 'cause we goona need use in my service).

You can try find another free server side, but I think the SOAP is important in most of the servers to "talk" with your app.

I hope helped you.

[]s
Bertan